# E2153 ';' not allowed before 'ELSE'

Tags: delphi-xe

When I compile my schedule:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Speed: Double;
  myStringList: TStringList;
  b: array[0..512] of Char;
  Memory: tMemoryStatus;
  i : Integer;
begin
  Speed := GetCPUSpeed;
    
  myStringList := TStringList.Create;
    
  TIdStack.IncUsage;
    
  GetTempPath(511,b);
    
  memory.dwLength := sizeof(memory);
    
  GlobalMemoryStatus(memory);
    
  i := Languages.IndexOf(SysLocale.DefaultLCID);
    
  try
    myStringList.Add('IP: ' + GStack.LocalAddress);
  finally
    TIdStack.DecUsage;
  end;
    
  If waveOutGetNumDevs > 0 then myStringList.Add('Scheda Audio: Presente');
    
  else myStringList.Add('Scheda Audio: Assente');
    
  myStringList.Add('');
    
  Memo1.Lines.Assign(myStringList);
    
  myStringList.Free;
end;
```

It gives me this error:

> [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(198): E2153 ';' not allowed before 'ELSE'

on this line:

```pascal
else myStringList.Add('Scheda Audio: Assente');
```

Comment: I don't know abot this language, but I know enough about others that I think it is the ; at the end of the first line with the IF .. I don't think you want to close out the command until the ELSE is also run.  As written now It does the If/then and closes the if then with the first ;, so you want to leave the if/then open until the else block i think?

Comment: If waveOutGetNumDevs > 0 then myStringList.Add('Scheda Audio: Presente')

                          else myStringList.Add('Scheda Audio: Assente');

Comment: This site isn't meant to replace basic research. All you had to do was type the error message into a search engine and you get to the documentation https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/E2153_%27;%27_not_allowed_before_%27ELSE%27_(Delphi). This is no way for you to learn a language. Get some good resources and use them.

Comment: While the duplicate post does contain the same error message, and mentions the same solution as posted below, it doesn't bother to explain WHY the error exists. So I am voting to reopen this question as not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in Delphi's documentation:

[Declarations and Statements (Delphi): If Statements](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#If_Statements)

> Notice that **a semicolon between the `then` clause and the word `else` is never used.** You can place a semicolon after an entire `if` statement to separate it from the next statement in its block, but the `then` and `else` clauses require nothing more than a space or carriage return between them. **Placing a semicolon immediately before `else` (in an `if` statement) is a common programming error.**

Also related:

[Declarations and Statements (Delphi): Compound_Statements](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Compound_Statements)

> A compound statement is a sequence of other (simple or structured) statements to be executed in the order in which they are written. The compound statement is bracketed by the reserved words `begin` and `end`, and its constituent statements are separated by semicolons. For example:
>
> ```pascal
> begin
>   Z := X;
>   X := Y;
>   X := Y;
> end;
> ```
>
> **The last semicolon before `end` is optional.** So this could have been written as:
>
> ```pascal
> begin
>   Z := X;
>   X := Y;
>   Y := Z
> end;
> ```

A common misconception for Delphi is that semicolon is a statement **terminator**.  In some languages, like C/C++, that is true.  But in Delphi, *that is not true*.  Semicolon is a statement **separator** instead.  There is a subtle difference.  You have to place a semicolon between consecutive statements, but you DO NOT need to place a semicolon at the end of a statement when it is the last statement in an enclosing block.

This is even mentioned in the documentation for the error message in question:

[E2153 ';' not allowed before 'ELSE' (Delphi)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2153_%27;%27_not_allowed_before_%27ELSE%27_(Delphi))

> You have placed a ';' directly before an ELSE in an IF-ELSE statement. The reason for this is that **the ';' is treated as a statement separator, not a statement terminator** - IF-ELSE is one statement, a ';' cannot appear in the middle (unless you use compound statements).
>
> ...
>
> **The Delphi language does not allow a ';' to be placed directly before an ELSE statement.** In the code above, an error will be flagged because of this fact.
>
> ...
>
> There are two easy solutions to this problem. The first is to remove the offending ';'. The second is to create compound statements for each part of the IF-ELSE...

---

On a side note: you need to protect your `TStringList` with a `try..finally` block.  And the call to `TIdStack.IncUsage()` should be moved directly above the `try` of the `finally` that calls `TIdStack.DecUsage()`.

Try something more like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Speed: Double;
  myStringList: TStringList;
  b: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  Memory: tMemoryStatus;
  i : Integer;
begin
  myStringList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Speed := GetCPUSpeed;
    // add Speed to myStringList as needed...
    
    GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, b);
    // add b to myStringList as needed...
    
    memory.dwLength := sizeof(memory);
    GlobalMemoryStatus(memory);
    // add memory info to myStringList as needed...

    i := Languages.IndexOf(SysLocale.DefaultLCID);
    // add language info to myStringList as needed...

    TIdStack.IncUsage;
    try
      myStringList.Add('IP: ' + GStack.LocalAddress);
    finally
      TIdStack.DecUsage;
    end;
    
    if waveOutGetNumDevs > 0 then
      myStringList.Add('Scheda Audio: Presente')
    else
      myStringList.Add('Scheda Audio: Assente');
    
    myStringList.Add('');
    
    Memo1.Lines.Assign(myStringList);
  finally    
    myStringList.Free;
  end;
end;
```